# Call JSON with subscribe or promise

Tags: json, angular6, primeng

If I use the promise function, I get the Error:

> **Property 'TEST' does not exist on type 'Object'**
>   my ServiceClass

with the method:

```
  getTEST() {
   return this.http.get(this.configUrl)
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => <Tariftabelle[]> res.TEST)
    .then(data => { return data; });
  }
```

And my json-Date:

```
{
     "TEST": [
      {"leistung": "hello", "sb": "World"},
      {"leistung": "hellooo", "sb": "Test-Wordl"}
      ],
      "TEST2": [
      {"leistung": "hola", "basic": "1", "premium": "2", "exzellent": "3"},
      {"leistung": "hola two", "basic": "2", "premium": "4", "exzellent": "6"},
      {"leistung": "hola three", "basic": "4", "premium": "7", "exzellent": "9"}
    ]
}
```

or how can iIuse subscribe without promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {

    getTEST(): Observable<any> {
       return this.http.get(this.configUrl);   
    }

}
```

Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    data: any;

    constructor(private myServ: MyService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myServ.getTEST().subscribe(res => {
            this.data = res;
        });
    }
}
```

Template

```
<pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>
```

As you can see in the init of your component you subscribe for the service `getTEST` request. In the subscribe, when you receive json data, you assign them to your local `data` variable. Now you can access it into your template.

Comment: the console.log show me the right json object, how can i return this?

Comment: what do you need to do? where do you want to return that? do you need to access these data into component?

Comment: in my other component i use the  return this.http.get(this.configUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => <Tariftabelle[]> res.TEST);